# Connect monitor to my PC without a graphics port

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi, displayport

I have a PC with a LG monitor 34UC98-W (that only has HDMI , Display port) and a [P9X79](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P9X79/) motherboard with no output graphics port of its own. My graphics card had some problems and I had to send it for repair.

I wanted to know if there is anyway for me to connect my PC to my monitor. Right now I'm using remote desktop from my tablet (it's borrowed and I have to return it) to connect to my files on PC. I don't have much GPU heavy usage needs right now, just having access to the hard drive and CPU is good enough.

Comment: A cheap graphics card is less than $10 on fleabay ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a cheap graphics card on hand is a good solution for a number of reasons.

1. You can wait until there is a cheap "loss leader" graphics card on sale and buy it new, so you know it works properly.
2. If you have a sudden graphics problem with a desktop computer, it can save you a trip to the computer repair shop.
3. A swappable graphics card is a good troubleshooting tool.
4. If your graphics card dies during the weekend, you can swap it with the spare graphics card and continue to use the same computer until you can get to a computer store to buy a replacement graphics card.